# Implementing an FTP Client in C# using TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, ftp, stream, networkstream

I've been messing around with TCP sockets in C#, and I'm having some trouble communicating with an FTP server I have set up. I can connect initially and get the 220 message, but when I send the "USER nrcrast" command, I never get a response, and the DataAvailable property returns false. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code so far:

```
namespace TCPClient
{
public partial class TCPClientForm : Form
{


    private TcpClient myClient;
    NetworkStream stream;

    public TCPClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        send();

    }

    void send()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                myClient = new TcpClient("nrcrast.dyndns.info", 21);
                break;
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
        stream = myClient.GetStream();
        int sendOffset = 0;
        int recOffset=0;

        int dataLength;
        Byte[] receiveData = new Byte[256];


        // wait for a response
        dataLength = stream.Read(receiveData, recOffset, receiveData.Length);
        String recvdMessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveData, 0, dataLength);
        Console.WriteLine(recvdMessage.ToString());
         recOffset+=dataLength;


        String message = "USER nrcrast";
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        sendOffset += data.Length;

        // wait for a response
        while (!stream.DataAvailable)
        {
        }
        dataLength = stream.Read(receiveData, 0, receiveData.Length);
        recvdMessage = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveData, 0, dataLength);
        Console.WriteLine(recvdMessage.ToString());


    }


}
```

Comment: I am assuming that you are doing this as a learning exercise, and that's why you are not using the FtpWebRequest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class, right?

Comment: ... or [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Comment: Yeah. Just trying to understand the protocol itself so I can later code an FTP client for windows phone. (I don't believe the ftpwebrequest is available for windows phone coding)

Comment: If you end up needing to write your own for Win Phone then you may want to look into maybe using/fixing the [OpenNETCF FTP Library](http://ftp.codeplex.com/) instead of writing your own from the ground up.

Answer (score 5):

A shoot in the dark, you need to put a carriage return and new line at the end of the command

```
String message = "USER nrcrast\r\n";
```

Comment: Actually, the specification says that commands should end with a CRLF. So it would be `"USER nrcrast\r\n"`. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959

Comment: @JimMischel yep!, thats it, i just checked.

Comment: Microsoft, unsurprisingly, always against all standards! Just a comment, nobody upset please!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in looking over someone's shoulder on a similar project (not saying its perfect), I did the same thing a long time ago (this was back in .net 1.1, and ported it to .net 2.0 when the ssl stream stuff was added).

there are some tricky pieces to the FTP protocols with respect to timings of when you send commands, when the server expects you to open the data connection, when you read the server response, and so forth (depending on active / passive modes).

anyway, feel free to look over [My FTP Client Library](http://sanity-free.com/net/nullfx.net-source.zip) source code for reference as you do your own implementation.  it's a pretty complete implementation and does auth ssl/tls as well.